# CSS Background Image Won't Work on Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have problem with CSS background in Chrome, the image won't show up. It is work on Firefox, even IE, but not Chrome.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="1181" class="archieve_thumb" style="width:98px; height:120px; border:1px solid #b0b0b0;">
<div class="archieve_thumb_img" style="width:19px; height:117px; padding:3px 0 0 79px; margin:0; background:url('/filesPreview/mini_1_z2KFeeUjy9.jpg'); border:0;">
<span class="archieve_thumb_delete"><a id="delete" href="delete.php?pageID=1181"><img src="http://myedisi.ursabyte.com/styles/img/icon_delete.png"/></a></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Am I using the wrong doctype?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Here is the screenshot on Chrome and Firefox

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

#### UPDATE

This is weird, I inspect the html using Chrome Developer Tool, and this is what I got.

[image: Weird HTML]

It seems my code is unreachable, as you can see, there is no child element on archieve_thumb element

P.S : I am just rewriting old code, not my code actually.

#### UPDATE

I am sorry guys, its because of the javascript, nothing related to css. I am sorry for the inconvenience. A bit weird javascript behaviour though, on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old doctype, try the html5 one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

What do you see when you inspect the image? Are you able to load the image by itself in a new tab?

The only time I've seen that happen is when AdBlock blocks the image because of the class name or id, do you have any plugins that might block them?

Comment: confirmed. under chrome, using XHTML 1.0 strict requires a browser refresh to show the images, but setting the DTD to HTML 5 requires no refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/eEPdR/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/Ta8SN/

Comment: I've tried the <!DOCTYPE html> but it doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: @DomDay That is weird, that does work on Chrome, but why it doesn't on my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="1181" class="archieve_thumb" style="width:98px; height:120px; border:1px solid #b0b0b0;">
<div class="archieve_thumb_img" style="width:19px; height:117px; padding:3px 0 0 79px; margin:0;background:url(http://www.soneribank.com/images/soneri-direct-1.png); border:0;">
<span class="archieve_thumb_delete"><a id="delete" href="delete.php?pageID=1181"><img src="http://myedisi.ursabyte.com/styles/img/icon_delete.png"/></a></span>
</div>    
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S77xz/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `background:url(http://www.soneribank.com/images/soneri-direct-1.png) no-repeat 0 0;` no-repeat and 0 0!